# await page.cookies() not returning cookies seen in response header

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am executing a basic puppeteer script that opens a webpage looks at response values and then pulls the cookies.

In the example below the response header has the following key values:

```
page.on('response', response => {
  const req = response.request();
  const resp = response;
  let result = {};
  result['method'] = req.method;
  result['status'] = resp.status;
  result['url'] = req.url;
  result['headers'] = resp.headers;


// Output of result['headers'] shortened for example
     u'server': u'Microsoft-IIS/7.5',
     u'set-cookie': u'A6=030uxloava000EG.000010000; expires=Mon, 16-Apr-2018 21:30:52 GMT; domain=.serving-sys.com; path=/\nC6=; expires=Mon, 16-Apr-2018 21:30:52 GMT; domain=.serving-sys.com; path=/\nD3=; expires=Mon, 16-Apr-2018 21:30:52 GMT; domain=.serving-sys.com; path=/\nu2=7f11f3f6-8979-4adc-824e-4d43b67f9b374ib310; expires=Mon, 16-Apr-2018 21:30:52 GMT; domain=.serving-sys.com; path=/',
     u'x-powered-by': u'ASP.NET'},
```

In that header you'll see a set-cookie but when I call await page.cookies() right after page.on('response'... :

```
    const cookies = await page.cookies();
```

const cookies will be []. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 32):

The `response` event fires before the request has actually completed. You could use `requestfinished` instead, but if you don't care about the individual HTTP requests (for all scripts, images, etc.), you can get the "final cookies" with just:

```js
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto('https://www.google.com')
const cookies = await page. Cookies()
```

Comment: Maybe just a typo but in puppeteer 21.6.0, this should be page.cookies() < (lowercase 'c')